# Adding classes onto UIView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift4

So i've been writing my application programmatically and have come across this problem... Can anyone see why my labels and text views are not where I'd expect them to be (below the navigation bar and on the cyan UIView).

[image]

My code for the creation of this looks like: 
    class AdminNewsController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
let mainView = UIView()
let picker = UIPickerView()

override func loadView() {

    view = UIView()
    view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    view.backgroundColor = AMA_Constants.AppPrimaryColor

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = AMA_Constants.AppSecondaryColor
    self.navigationItem.title = "Admin - News"

    newsCategoryPicker.delegate = self
    newsCategoryPicker.dataSource = self
    newsCategoryPicker.isHidden = true

    view.addSubview(mainView)
    setupMainView()

}

func setupMainView() {

    //mainView.backgroundColor = AMA_Constants.AppSecondaryColor
    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    }
    mainView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/2).isActive = true

    addViews()

}


private func addViews() {
    mainView.addSubview(newsItemHeading)
    mainView.addSubview(newsTitleTextEdit)
    mainView.addSubview(newsSubTitleTextEdit)
    mainView.addSubview(newsCategoryTextEdit)
    //mainView.addSubview(newsCategoryPicker)
    mainView.addSubview(newsBodyTextEdit)
    mainView.addSubview(newsImageView)
    //view.addSubview(newsImageSelectButton)
    mainView.addSubview(newsSubmitButton)
    mainView.addSubview(newsResetButton)

}
```

All of the constraining occurs after this with each item taking the lead off this:

```
        newsItemHeading.anchor(mainView.topAnchor, left: mainView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: AMA_Constants.Alignment_Space.PaddingVerticalExternal, leftConstant: AMA_Constants.Alignment_Space.PaddingHorizontalExternal, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

which is a wrapper from www.letsbuildthatapp.com.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong in aligning things correctly?

Many thanks

Comment: For your `newsTitleTextEdit`, are you doing `newsTitleTextEdit.anchor(mainView.topAnchor, ...)`? Or are you doing `newsTitleTextEdit.anchor(newsItemHeading.bottomAnchor, ...)`?

Comment: Things look fine to me. I think the problem is in either the wrapper you’re using or in the constraining code that you didn’t share. Whenever you see the “position is ambiguous” message, then Autolayout is confused. And when it’s confused, it usually just throws everything in the top left corner. Since the `mainView` is correctly placed, then that’s proof that the code that you’ve shared is correct. Could we see the code for the constraints on the subviews?

Comment: ABeard89 the wrapper is proven to work elsewhere so haven’t looked into it any more.

Comment: DonMag - I’m taking newstitleTextEdit.topAnchor = newsItemHeading.bottomAnchor

Comment: @AlTopping - ok, step 1: add **only** `newItemHeading` ... assuming it gets positioned behind the nav bar, double-check the value of `AMA_Constants.Alignment_Space.PaddingVerticalExternal` ... assuming it is correct (i.e. *not* -40), while in Debug View Hierarchy select that object (it's a label?) and check the values in Object and Size Inspector panes. Also, since it looks like the constraints are not being set at all, double-check that your code is *really* calling your `.anchor()` lines.

Comment: I’m inclined to agree with @DonMag. It doesn’t look like the constraints are being set at all. As he suggested, add and constrain them one at a time. Without seeing the wrapper or your code that uses it, then that’s as good advice as I can give.

Comment: I found my issue, you were right. As much as I was using the correct functions to constrain my view I wasn’t calling the fiction .